# What would be a good query to find my previous rank in this score table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently using this query to find the rank of a player:

```
select
    coalesce(
        (
            select count(1)
            from scores b
            where
                b.top > a.top OR
                (
                    b.top = a.top AND
                    b.time < a.time
                )
        ), 0
    ) + 1 Rank
from
    Scores a
where
    user = ?
```

I have a score table like this:

```
id           int
user         varchar(100)
time         int (timestamp)
top          int
```

And a recent table like this:

```
id           int
user         varchar(100)
time         int (timestamp)
score        int
istopscore   int (boolean 1/0)
```

The database is already filled with data, so I cannot simply change the structure of the database. There are over 200.000 rows in the recent table, so sorting takes a lot of time. I am trying to find a way to do this as quickly as possible.

How would I find the previous rank of a player? Here is what I have tried:

```
select
    coalesce(
        (
            select count(1)
            from recent b
            where
                b.istopscore = 1 AND
                (
                    (
                        b.score > a.top AND
                        b.time <= a.time
                    ) OR
                    (
                        b.score = a.top AND
                        b.time < a.time
                    )
                )
            ), 0) + 1 Rank
from scores a
where user = ?
```

The problem with this query is that if a user has scored multiple new top scores, it counts all of them, so it does not give the correct result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) as an example?

Comment: @RobbieAverill http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bc381/2

Comment: Can you define `previous rank` a little better? What makes a `previous rank`, is it "what would this users current rank be ignoring their top score?" or is it "what was this users rank at time t?"

Comment: @Scott I want to know the rank at the time the player scored their top score. So it might have been last week for example. So, yes, their rank at time t. But what makes it difficult is that the recent table contains multiple top scores per user. So I need to some way calculate every user's top score at that time to know the top score of one player. But it needs not to take a lot of time to execute the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your query is almost right. To overcome the problem with multiple top scores you can use `count(distinct username)`, like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bc381/10):

```
select
    coalesce(
        (
            select count(distinct username)
            from recent b
            where
                b.istopscore = 1 AND
                (
                    (
                        b.score > a.top AND
                        b.time <= a.time
                    ) OR
                    (
                        b.score = a.top AND
                        b.time < a.time
                    )
                )
            ), 0) + 1 Rank
from scores a
where username = 'Echo'
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)